# Абстрактный метод

Tags: java

В чем конкретно функция абстрактного метода? И чем он отличается от не абстрактного? В абстрактных классах.

Comment: Зачем минусуете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция абстрактного метода состоит в определении контракта и шаблона для реализации конкретной функциональности в производных классах. Соответственно абстрактный метод отличается тем, что не имеет реализации. В случае абстрактного класса, не абстрактный метод предоставляет реализацию по умолчанию, тогда как абстрактный метод не предоставляет какой-либо реализации.

Answer (score 1):

Абстрактный означает *неважно как*, скажем вам ставят задачу *добраться* до от пункта А до пункта Б. *Добраться* здесь абстрактно (для ставящего задачу) - неважно как, на машине, пешком, самолетом, на пароходе или ковре-самолете - это никого не интересует. Тот кому предстоит добираться вынужден будет эту абстракцию *добраться* наполнить реальным смыслом, то есть, как принято говорить в Java/ООП *реализовать* или *implement* уже конкретно. В терминах Java это означает реализовать абстрактный метод. Примерно так:

```
abstract class Маршрут {
   abstract void добраться();
}

class АвиаМаршрут extends Маршрут {
   @Override
   void добраться() {
       полететь(купитьБилет());
   }
}
```

P.S. Извиняюсь за кириллические идентификаторы :)